# Как написать функцию сравнения строк?

Tags: c

Для своей программы я должен написать функцию сравнения строк, часть строки мы вводим, а вторую строку считываем из файла. В файле у нас есть строки типа `Имя;Фамилия;Телефон`. Если у нас есть любые совпадения в строках (имеется ввиду не часть имени или фамилии, а полностью написанные) мы должны вывести весь контакт.

Answer (score 3):

Подойдет стандартная функция `strcmp()` из `string.h` ?

Comment: У меня не получилось применить её.

Comment: Почему? Там же все элементарно.

Comment: Она работает, если я ввожу полностью всю строку, например, как она записана в файле, а мне надо, чтобы функция уже при совпадении имени выводила весь контакт.

Comment: А, если нужно найти, входит ли введенный фрагмент в строку из файла, то можно применить strstr()

Comment: что-что я об этом не слышал, что это за функция?

Comment: Стандартная функция. Смотрите мануалы.